# Native JAI is false in geoserver

Tags: geoserver, sql-server

Below given is screen shot of GeoServer 2.13.0 installed on my machine. 
Configuration of my machine is :
Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3770 CPU @3.40 GHZ

Installed Memory 16.0 GB

OS Windows 10 64-bit

[image: Geoserver on windows 10]

I am displaying WMS layer using leaflet to draw tiles on map.Database is SQL SERVER 2016. The problem is that mostly rendering of tiles is slow on map. When I investigated further, I found that Native JAI and Native JAI ImageIO is false and this was required for good performance : [Geoserver Running in production environment](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/production/java.html)

When I tried "Installing native JAI on Windows" in the following link :
[Installing native JAI on Windows](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/production/java.html) few links were not working. When I download JAI and JAI ImageIO from the given link they were throwing error that JRE 1.4 must be installed. However , on my machine JRE 1.8 is installed. Check the screenshot given below.

[image]

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The docs are old and native JAI is on the "way of the dodo", I believe in most of our installations we are not adding it anymore (mostly because it does not have some basic fixes present in jai-ext and won't handle NODATA).

It will help you on Windows under the following conditions:

- Your slowness is on rendering raster data (not vector data sources from SQL Server)
- You don't need NODATA support
- You can run on 32bit binaries (native JAI is not available on 64 bits on Windows)
- You're not hitting any known JAI bug

If instead you're mostly rendering vector data and the slowness is visible to the naked eye on light load, it's most likely a database query issue (maybe it's not using indexes, maybe you're just trying to render too much data, you did not provide enough context to tell). Suggestion, switch the logging level to GEOTOOLS_DEVELOPER_LOGGING and check what the queries are doing.

Comment: Is there any way we can assign more memory to Geoserver ? See memrory usage is very less. Hopefully, that could help to improve performance. In SQL we have created all required spatial indexes and yes, sometimes there are a lot of data we try to draw on map. These data are LINESTRING stored in SQL Server table as Geometry.

Comment: This is a different question. Please open a separate question here, or, if you don't actually know what the issue is and are trying to get, better get on geoserver-users and ask there, providing some indication of hardware, styles, scale dependencies and data size. See: http://geoserver.org/comm/

Comment: These docs are from Geoserver 2.14. How they can be old ?

Comment: Because they have not been updated in ages? We need contributors for updating docs, if you are interested :)